# Error: at least one entry of 'x' must be positive. How to fix this error?

Tags: r

I used the RVAideMemoire package for the G.test function.

```
   > head(datamixG)
            [,1] [,2]
      [1,]    0    5
      [2,]    0    5
      [3,]    0    2
      [4,]    0    0
      [5,]    0    2
      [6,]    0    1
```

When I tried to use the G.test, I got this error.

```
    > apply(datamixG, 1, G.test)
    Error in chisq.test(x, p = p) : 
      at least one entry of 'x' must be positive
```

Is there a way to eliminate the error and have R analyze the 0?

The G.test tests to see if for example, 0:5 is significantly different from a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: what is this G.test you speak of

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RVAideMemoire/docs/G.test
It's similar to chi-square, except has the advantage of being additive.
http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statgtestgof.html

Comment: You might want `ks.test`, or any other function that returns the likelihood ratio test statistic or performs a goodness-of-fit.

Comment: @RichardScriven I have to use the G test for this. I just realized that adding one to every number makes the G.test invalid. Do you know of another way to get around the error without adding one to every number?

Comment: [This might be useful](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/sta321/mleexample.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This will add 1 to every number in datamixG

```
apply(datamixG +1 , 1, G.test)
```

Comment: Thank MrFlick! It worked perfectly. 
Do you know of any way to organize the results of the G.test better in R? You get a separate G-value, df and p-value for each row which is pretty messy. For example to somehow get a list of the G values, df and p-values? I also need to sum all the G-values and df.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this as a separate question. I am not familiar with the `G.test` function or even what package it comes from.

Comment: Okay, thank you! It comes from this package, just in case you were curious 
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RVAideMemoire/docs/G.test

Comment: "Worked perfectly"?. All it did was make the error go away. Why is that perfect? You don't seem to understand the test. Why should adding 1 to every value result in a valid result from the test?

Comment: @BondedDust , I only meant it worked perfectly as in the error was fixed, I'll admit I didn't check, so it wasn't actually perfect. I only just got around to checking today that the G and p values were the same. I've never used the test and I'm not very familiar with it, I'm learning. I see now why it's invalid. Do you know how I can get around that error?